# How to use "setenv" command in zsh shell?

Tags: zsh, setenv

I tried to install OMNeT++ in my notebook (macOS Catalina 10.15). I had follow install guide from OMNeT++ official site. But this guide description below:

> OMNeT++ needs its bin/ and tools/macosx/bin directories to be in the path. To add them PATH temporarily (in the current shell only), change into the OMNeT++ directory and source the setenv script:

```
$ cd omnetpp-5.6.1
$. setenv
```

I knew "setenv" command only use "csh".

Can I change the default shell (zsh) to use the above command for the shell?

Comment: There is no zsh command named `setenv`. If you need such a command, you have to write it by yourself. The equivalent to the csh/tcsh _setenv_ in zsh is `export VARIABLE=VALUE`. If you want to source a file named `setenv`, make sure that the file exists and its content indeed contains zsh commands.

Comment: @user1934428 : When I did execute "source setenv" command in "omnetpp-5.6.2" folder that anything no shown error. Also I thought it's process successed.  But from your comments, I knew I was wrong. So I created the ".zshrc" file and used "export" to write the relevant path. Is this correct?

Comment: I don't know whether it is correct for **your** use case. What you essentially did is that whenever you start a _new interactive zsh process_, the .zshrc will be processed, including the `export` commands you have diligently put there. If you want this to happen, this is of course correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't talking about the `csh` builtin; they're referring to a script named `setenv` that is to be sourced (using the `.` command, which is somewhat hidden in your question by its proximity to the prompt).

```
cd omnetpp-5.6.1
. setenv
```

If you are using `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`, etc, you could use `source` as a synonym for `.`:

```
source setenv
```

Comment: Very useful :D. Thx. My thoughts were too short. I was thinking about thinking a little deeper.

Comment: @chepner : `source` and `.` are not synoyms (at least not in zsh), thought they are very similar. With `source x`, `x` is searched first in the current directory and then in the PATH. With `. x` it is the other way around.

Comment: Yeah, it's always in the back of my mind that there are shells that make slight distinctions between the two, but I never remember what those distinctions are.